# Connect JavaScript with Spring to count user click and mongo document size

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have some situation and I dont know even how to start.

So basically I have for example collection `adventureholidays` inside that collection I have many documents, and I'm calling it like
this

```
@GetMapping("/getRandomSummerCamps")
    public String getRandomSummerCamps(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("randomSummerCamps", adventureHolidaysService.getRandomSummerCamps());
        return "randomSummerCamps";
    }
```

So that controller will return me one random document from collection `adventureholidays` that have type `summerCamps` like String.

That works fine.

Now, on my page I have button `Randomize again` and actually that button is calling that URL and it show to user again random document
from that collection.

What I want to achieve is that somehow I need to get numbers of document in that collection and if user `clicks == numbersOfDocument`
show him page for example No more documents in collection, and also would be much better If I somehow manage to make so
program will not return two same documents but still count clicks and again if `clicks == numbersOfDocument` show him page for example No more documents in collection

I don't know how to connect JS clicks and Spring to count numbers of document. Any help, advice, resource?

Comment: If the button calls the API, can't you count api calls on the server side instead of counting clicks?

Comment: How I can achieve that? I need that implementation in Spring or in JS? How I can also achieve to not show two same documents? Sorry, I'm really beginner to JS and just doing researches while building this stuff, and also I'm trying to do as much as I can stuff in Spring and Java

Comment: You can track the number of clicks in JS, just by creating a separate variable and the on successful API call increase this variable, after that on backend you need to receive this variable and to theck if ```variable == numberOfDocuments.length```, if yes, just return that there are no documents

Comment: Okay, thank you, tell me about that part when I need to receive that variable on back-end, you mean Spring, how I can achieve that? How I can consume variables from JS in Spring, or I didn't understand you well?